# Splitting a line from a file into different lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

My program is supposed to take input from the user and read a file with the name input. Read file gets saved into a dictionary called portfolio and from there all I have to do is sort each line in the portfolio into keys and values.

Here's my code.

```
portfolio = {}
portfolio = file_read() #Reads the file through a function
if file_empty(portfolio) == True or None: #nevermind this, it works
    print "The file was not found."
else:
    print "The file has successfully been loaded"

for line in portfolio:
    elements = line.strip().split(",") #separate lists by comma
    print elements[0] #using this to check
    print elements[1] #if it works at all
```

All this does is print the first letter in the first line, which is S. And apparently elements[1] is supposed to be the second letter but index is out of range, please enlighten me what might be wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: why you using same variable portfolio name for two different things???

Comment: is that you file_read function will return values as dcitionary??

Comment: plz share your whole code???

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/790100c7d8d99f50be90
@Hackaholic
Nevermind line 64-68, only trying different stuff right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `file_read()` is reading the file into a string.

Then `for line in portfolio:` is iterating through each *character* in that string.

Then `elements = line.strip().split(",")` will give you a list containing one character, so trying to get `elements[1]` is past the bounds of the list.

If you want to read the whole contents of the file into a string called `portfolio`, you can iterate through each *line* in the string using

```
for line in porfolio.split('\n'):
    ...
```

But the more usual way of iterating through lines in a file would be

```
with open(filename,'r') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
         ....
```

Comment: How do I make it not split it into a list containing one character? I want it to catch everything before the commas. @khelwood

Comment: Your problem is that `for line in porfolio` is assigning `line` to _one character at a time_. Change that as I said in my answer.

Comment: It worked fine with     for line in portfolio.split('\n'). I get a new error when trying to use the file outside of the for-loop now, index is always out of range. @khelwood

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with this code:

```
    for line in minfil :
    line = line.strip()
    elements = line.split(",")
    portfolio[str(elements[0])] = [(int(elements[1]),float(elements[2]), str(elements[3]))]
```